# Login api gives response token

Tags: java, android, android-volley, mean.io

My server (a Mean.io web app) gives a token as a response when I want to log in into my Android app.

Is it the right way to do it like this when a user wants to login?

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
token = jObj.getString("token");

if(token != null) {
    // user successfully logged in
    // Create login session
    session.setLogin(true);
}
```

Comment: This probably depends on the specifics of your API, which I'm not familiar with, however I think you'll be required to make a local copy of that token and persist it throughout the session. I think the validity of your login state can be inferred from whether interactions can be successfully implemented using your local token, so you might want to try performing some I/O and see whether it works.